# Url special character using get request

Tags: php, html, special-characters, forms, url-encoding

When I click the submit button on the page rendered by the below code, I want my url to look like 
`locl.cms.com/upload/season.php?sid=20&currentPage=1`

```
echo '<form action="" method="get"> 
  <button id="previouspage" name="'.$encodedURL.'" type="submit" 
    value="'.$page.'">Previous Page</button> 
  <button id="nextpage" name="currentPage" type="submit" 
    value="'.$pageN.'">Next Page</button> 
  </form>'; 
echo "Inside Div"; 
echo '</div>';
```

where

```
$url='sid='.$sid.'&currentPage';
$encodedURL=urlencode($url);
```

when i click `Previous Page` button, my url becomes `locl.cms.com/upload/season.php?sid%253D20%2526currentPage=1`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you assigning $encodedUrl to name?

Comment: coz name get appended to the url . if i put name = something, the url becomes www.abc.com/abc.php?something= .

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form with `method="get"`, the `action` attribute of the form becomes the URL and the form input elements including buttons contribute towards the `name=value` query string appended to the URL, which then gets sent to the server. Here the name and value will be URL encoded ( thats what you see as special chars, in OP ).

```
// The URL making pseudo code ( run by the browser )

if ( form.method is-fully-qualified-with-protocol-etc )
    base_url = form.action
elseif ( form.action is-full-path-begining-with-forward-slash )
    base_url = page.protocol+'://'+page.url.hostname+':'page.url.port+form.action
elseif ( form.action is-a-relative-path-or-blank )
    base_url = page.url+form.action

encoded_form_input = ''
for-each ( form.input_elements as input_element )
    encoded_form_input += urlencode(input_element.name) + '=' + urlencode(input_element.value) + '&'

final_url = base_url + '?' + encoded_form_input;
```

One exception to the set of inputs encoded into the URL is the `button` input, it will only be the button you pressed. Other buttons are ignored.

This hopefully should give you some pointers to why you re not getting the URL you were expecting.

Comment: thanks. But what should i do to get the desired url?

Comment: Sorry mate, there is a lot of information missing in the OP. Hence the generic answer. Tell me what is `sid` and what do you expect the URL to be when clicking on each of the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Instead of button, i used href and its working perfectly now.

echo '<a href="season.php?sid='.$id.'&currentPage='.$pageN.'">';
echo "Next Page >></a><br>";
echo '<a href="season.php?sid='.$id.'&currentPage='.$page.'">';
echo "Previous Page >></a>";
 echo '</div>';

Comment: Sorry for the missing info about my code, next-time i will be more specific.